Can't compile libpipewire program
I'm trying to compile the code from this guide https://web.archive.org/web/20240105020743/https://docs.pipewire.org/page_tutorial2.html
Minimal code:
#include <pipewire/pipewire.h>

static void registry_event_global(void *data, uint32_t id,
            uint32_t permissions, const char *type, uint32_t version,
            const struct spa_dict *props)
{
    printf("object: id:%u type:%s/%d\n", id, type, version);
}

static const struct pw_registry_events registry_events = {
    PW_VERSION_REGISTRY_EVENTS,
    .global = registry_event_global,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}

gcc main.c -o test1 -lpipewire-0.2
Error: error: variable 'registry_events' has initializer but incomplete type
I can’t find in which header pw_registry_events is located

I have libpipewire-0.3 on my machine but does gcc main.c -o test1 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libpipewire-0.2) work?

no, the same error
how to install libpipewire-0.3? from sources? @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

You should follow README

solved by installing libpipewire-0.3 with apt
